# jpa criteria compare two strings in without considering spaces

Tags: java, jpa, compare, criteria

I think that it is a basic question, but I'm struggling to get an answer.

The question is: using `CriteriaBuilder` and Predicate how can I compare strings without considering spaces in the middle. For example: `"CH 525 kV AREIA 1077 PR"`. There isn't a "replace" function in `CriteriaBuilder` library.

```
cb.like(equipamento.get(EquipamentoBO_.txNomeLongo), "%" + dto.getTxNomeEquipamento().toUpperCase().replace(" ", "") + "%")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `function` method which should do the trick for you if you use `REPLACE` as the function to use:

```
cb.like(
          cb.function("REPLACE"
                 , String.class
                 , equipamento.get(EquipamentoBO_.txNomeLongo)
                 , cb.literal(" ")
                 , cb.literal(""))
          , "%" + dto.getTxNomeEquipamento().toUpperCase().replace(" ", "") + "%"
       )
```

Comment: The final code is: cb.like(
       cb.upper(cb.function("REPLACE"
                    , String.class
                    , equipamento.get(EquipamentoBO_.txNomeLongo)
                    , cb.literal(" ")
                    , cb.literal("")))
             , "%" + dto.getTxNomeEquipamento().toUpperCase().replace(" ", "") + "%"
          )

Comment: Great. Glad i could help