# How to fetch data from database by ignoring/replacing/trimming in between spaces of column value in CriteriaBuilder

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I found out how I can trim trailing and leading white space from a string, but could not find how to fetch data by replacing in-between spaces.

I have a column `1` in table `X`. In column `1`, I have two values: `"abcd"` and  `"ab cd"`. I want to fetch both values by passing `"abcd"` as search parameters to `criteriaBuilder`.

I have below for trailing and leading white space, can anyone please let me know how I can replace all space characters in `criteriaBuilder`?

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.trim(criteriaBuilder.upper(Column 1);
```

I couldn't get it to work for me exactly how I wanted, I tried adding changes and rebuild and restart.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278886/jpa-criteria-compare-two-strings-in-without-considering-spaces

Comment: criteriaBuilder.like(
                                criteriaBuilder.upper(criteriaBuilder.function("REPLACE" ,
                                        String.class ,criteriaBuilder.upper(addJoin.get("Code"))
                                , criteriaBuilder.literal(" ") ,
                                criteriaBuilder.literal(""))) , "%" +
                                pCode(filter.getCode()).toUpperCase().replace(" ", "") + "%" );

Comment: Above worked for me. thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, as explained in the question, that I have a table `X`. In that table I have a column `1`. In column `1`, I have two values: `"abcd"` and `"ab cd"`. I want to fetch both values by passing `"abcd"` as search parameters to `criteriaBuilder`.

I had the below code for leading and trailing white space, but it didn't work for `"ab cd"`, with white space not at the edge of a string.

Basically I wanted to compare strings between the input and database column value (replaced with space):

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.trim(criteriaBuilder.upper(Column 1);
```

I replaced this by

```
 Predicate postCodePredicate =  criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(criteriaBuilder.function("REPLACE",                                                                           String.class,                                                                          criteriaBuilder.upper(addJoin.get("Code")) ,                                                                          criteriaBuilder.literal(" ") ,                                                                           criteriaBuilder.literal(""))) ,                                                                          "%" + pCode(filter.getCode()).toUpperCase().replace(" ",   "") + "%" );
```

as suggested in [jpa criteria compare two strings in without considering spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278886/jpa-criteria-compare-two-strings-in-without-considering-spaces)

Basically it uses the function `criteriaBuilder` with `"REPLACE"`

```
criteriaBuilder.function("REPLACE",        
                        String.class,  
                        criteriaBuilder.upper(addJoin.get("Code")) ,  
                        //Expression above
                        criteriaBuilder.literal(" ") , 
                        criteriaBuilder.literal(""))) , 
                        "%" + pCode(filter.getCode()).toUpperCase().replace(" 
                        ",   "") + "%" )         //pCode(filter.getCode() is //your input search param
```

I call the function with the following parameters

```
public <T> Expression<T> function(String name, Class<T> returnType, Expression... arguments) {
    return new ParameterizedFunctionExpression(this, returnType, name, arguments);
}
```

You can also use `criteriaBuilder.equal` as shown below if you don´t want `criteriaBuilder.like`, just remove `"%"`

```
Predicate postCodePredicate =  criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(criteriaBuilder.function("REPLACE",                                                                            String.class,                                                                           criteriaBuilder.upper(addJoin.get("Code")) ,                                                                            criteriaBuilder.literal(" ") ,                                                                           criteriaBuilder.literal(""))) ,                                                                             pCode(filter.getCode()).toUpperCase().replace(" ",   "") );
```